# Proper place for readOnly attribute in Spring @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring

if a method from service layer calls a method from repository layer in the same transaction, then is it efficient to put readOnly attribute to service method or repository method?

Comment: I would go for service layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical location for the `@Transactional` annotation is in the service layer. Your service may call a number of repository methods so it is more efficient to have transactions spanning the single service call rather than have more for individual repository/DAO calls.

It is the correct approach if you have multiple DAOs injected into that service that need to work together in a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot but actually I want the transaction to continue in repository methods also. And they say that readonly is useful while accessing the datasource which is done by repository methods.

Comment: The transaction _will_ continue in the repository methods when the annotation is on the service layer. You can set the propagation for the repository methods but I think its cleaner overall to annotate the service methods :)